# What requirements does non-strict semantics of Haskell have on the evaluation strategy?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

The [Haskell language specification states](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/) that it is a non-strict language, but nothing about the evaluation strategy (like when and how an expression is evaluated, and to what level). It does mention the word "evaluate" several times when talking about pattern matching.

I have read a wonderful [tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness) about lazy evaluation and weak head normal form, but it is just an implementation strategy of some compiler, which I should not depend on when writing codes.

I come from a strict language background and I just don't feel right if I don't understand how my codes are executed. I wonder why the language specification does not define the evaluation strategy.

I hope someone can enlighten me. Thanks!

Comment: The Haskell language spec is intentionally very careful _not_ to specify too much about how expressions are evaluated, and this allows a great deal of latitude in designing compilers and runtimes. For example, Haskell programs can be compiled to run on FPGAs - i.e. your program is converted to a digital circuit - and GPUs as well as conventional CPUs.

I've found it is helpful to think of Haskell programs as describing more of _what_ you want to compute instead of a prescription for _how_ to compute it.

Comment: Out of print but available online, I found [The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/slpj-book-1987/), by Simon Peyton-Jones et al, immensely useful when I wrote a compiler much too long ago. (PDF looks broken in Firefox but seems OK in other viewers.)

Answer (score 10):

I would argue that trying to care about evaluation order is counter productive in Haskell. Not only is the language designed to make evaluation order irrelevant but the evaluation order can jump all over the place in strange and confusing ways. Additionally, the implementation has substantial freedom to execute things differently[1] or to vastly restructure your program[2] if the end result is still the same so different parts of the program might be evaluated in different ways.

The only real restriction is what evaluation strategies you *can't* use. For example, you can't always use strict evaluation because that would cause valid programs to crash or enter infinite loops.

```
const 17 undefined

take 10 (repeat 17)
```

That said, if you really care, one valid strategy you could possibly use to implement all of Haskell is lazy evaluation with thunks. Each value is represented in a box that either contains the value or a thunk subroutine that can be used to compute the value when you finally need to use it.

So when you write

```
let xs = 1 : []
```

You would be kind of doing this:

```
x --> {thunk}
```

If you never inspect the contents of x then the thunk stays unevaluated. However, if you ever do some pattern matching on the thunk then you need to evaluate the thunk to see what branch you take:

```
case xs of
  [] -> ...
  (y:ys) -> ...
```

Now, x's thunk is evaluated and the resulting value is stored in the box in case you ever need it. This is to avoid needing to recompute the thunk. Note that in the following diagram I'm using `Cons` to stand for the `:` list constructor

```
x ---> {Cons {thunk} {thunk}}
               ^       ^
               |       |
               y       ys
```

Of course, just the presence of the pattern math isn't enough you need first be forced to evaluate that pattern match in the first place. Ultimately, this boils down to your main function needing to print a value or something like that.

Another thing to point out is that we didn't immediately evaluate the contents of the Cons constructor when we first evaluate it. You can check this by running a program that doesn't use the contents of the list:

```
length [undefined, undefined]
```

Of course, when we actually use `y` for something then its corresponding thunk gets evaluated.

Additionally, you can use bang patterns to mark constructor fields as strict so they get immediately evaluated when the constructor gets evaluated (I don't remember if you need to turn an extension for this though)

```
data LazyBox   = LazyBox Int
data StrictBox = StrictBox !Int

case (LazyBox undefined) of (LazyBox _) -> 17   -- Gives 17

case (StrictBox undefined) of (StrictBox _) -> 17 -- *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

---

[1]: One important optimization that GHC does is using strict  evaluation in the sections that the strictness analyzers determines to be strict.

[2]: One of the most radical examples would be [deforestation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Short_cut_fusion).

Comment: Problem is that the performance can't be easily predicted if the evaluation strategy is not known.

Comment: @spockwang: If you really really want predictable performance then Haskell isn't the language for you. That said, its not that bad - lazy evaluation is more composable so you are less likely to find bad performance surprises as the codebase grows ([dons mentions that sometime during this video](http://www.haskellcast.com/episode/002-don-stewart-on-real-world-haskell/)). Anyway in terms of big-O, lazy evaluation usually doesn't make the runtime performance worst - the real issue is predicting space use and preventing space leaks.

Comment: @spockwang Performance can't be easily predicted in imperative languages with fixed evaluation strategies either! People (even very experienced programmers) are notoriously bad at predicting where the real performance bottlenecks are in the code they write. Hence "premature optimization is the root of all evil" and "always benchmark and profile your code before you optimise".

Comment: @spockwang Okasaki actually does quite a bit of performance prediction of lazy operations in the Functional Datastructures book.  It's not impossible, it just requires a bit more thought.

Comment: @Ben What I mean by performance is the time complexity of a snippet of code, not the performance of a whole program. It is usually easy to predict the time complexity with eager evaluation, but difficult with lazy evaluation because you don't know whether or when the thunk will be evaluated and how much space will be used which have a      big impact on the performance.

Comment: @spockwang: In practice predicting performance is actually not that bad. The only thing thats really though is detecting space leaks.